# Ways to improve the header title of a video in amp-video, instead of H3 tags

Tags: amp-html

I am looking for a visually better way of producing a title for each amp-video nested in a amp-accordion.

```
h3 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #19586d;
    background-color: #9DB6BD;
     text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  }

....

<section>
    <h3>myVideo</h3>
    <amp-video controls width="560" height="315" layout="responsive">
          <source src="https://example.com/upload/14.mp4" 
type="video/mp4" controlsList="nodownload"/>
                <div fallback><p>This browser does not support the video element.</p></div>
    </amp-video>
</section>
```

I have tried amp-fonts and amp-banner. Can somebody suggest options available for rendering the title which I currently have in H3 tags, so that it is responsive.

Comment: What you mean with render?

Comment: render = Something that looks better.